# Nhibernate schema clause

Tags: nhibernate

How do I use the schema clause on a bag object in Nhibernate mapping? I have an table that I need to specify the schema for and the nhibernate documentation talks about table schema but I can't find any further details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an attribute you put on the `<class>` element when you define it. So whatever the class is you're using in the bag, go to its mapping and add `schema="whatever"`.